# How to set Terrain View in Map View in android?

Tags: android, android-maps, android-mapview

I want to display terrain View in MapView

There are `mapView.setSatellite(true|false)` `mapView.setTraffic(true|false)` `mapView.setStreetView(true|false)` in `MapView` class as I found.

There is no method  to set terrain view.

but in the default **MAP application** comes with device. display Terrain View.
How can I achieve it.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thats cannot be done with Google Maps SDK provided to android for now.